# Azure Data Studio - not listing databases

Tags: azure-data-studio

When logged into Database Azure SQL Server from Azure Data Studio, doesn't list databases under connected server.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, and for some time now, I uninstalled it, I still couldn't solve it.